Is there a better way of querying foreign key relationships in rust-diesel?
I’m learning rust to move from django. Using diesel ORM i have a model consisting of users, posts (with a foreign key to user), and likes (with foreign keys to user and post).
This query is to retrieve all the posts the requesting user has like'd. I’d like to know if it’s correct, and if there are better/efficient ways to do this.
async fn liked_posts(user_id: web::Path<i32>) -> impl Responder {
    use schema::likes::dsl::*;
    use schema::posts::dsl::*;

    let conn = establish_connection();
    let results = likes.filter(user_id.eq(*user_id))
        .inner_join(posts)
        .select((posts::id, posts::user_id, posts::title, posts::content, posts::created_at))
        .load::<(i32, i32, String, String, chrono::NaiveDateTime)>(&conn)
        .expect("Error loading liked posts");

    let posts: Vec<PostResponse> = results.into_iter().map(|(id, user_id, title, content, created_at)| {
        PostResponse {
            id,
            user_id,
            title,
            content,
            created_at,
        }
    }).collect();

    HttpResponse::Ok().json(posts)
}

Django queries are much simpler but i’m looking for the most efficient way to complex query in rust as the point is it’s much much faster than python. Also what is the rust api equivalent of ‘related_name’ reverse foreign key relationship in django.

This belongs on code-review SE.

Asking if there's a simpler way to do something (where the something is a short snippet) is within SO territory as well. Transferring it to codereview will deprive future SO visitors who have the same question - not an unreasonable one to have - of the answer.

Is PostResponse the Diesel model of your posts table?  If so you could just do .select(PostResponse::as_select()).load(conn) to immediately get your posts vector.

Btw, it is unlikely you will see a difference in performance between Rust and Python/Django in this context. The bottleneck for complex queries is typically the database, not the client. This is the real reason why slow languages like Python are actually useful. So, even though I do believe that Rust is great, I think you overestimate it in this context.

Rust would still dominate for the api in terms of speed, less resource consumption, less cpu, memory? Essentially less server instances required compared to python for the same work load. I know that instagram use a forked version of python/django where they’ve made them 3 times faster than the original. Rust out of the box would still be faster which is why i’m trying it. Django does have many built in comforts like the admin panel though. Do you think it’s worth moving to rust? considering keeping server costs as low as possible, speed of writing the code is not a problem in this case.

@Awm yes, Rust will use less resources. But as I said, it may not be noticeable. Because typical app's performance is dominated by database, not languages performance. And
vastly. My suggestion is: do some tests and measure it first. It might not be worth it. Especially since Rust is very very difficult to work with.

Reading Diesel's Getting Started guide will go a long way. Your query is direct and performant, but the way to get the returned data is not very idiomatic. In particular, it is most common to create Rust structures that reflect the data you get back especially if its a whole row of a table. Using tuples is a more bespoke, one-off way to get load data. Your PostResponse could look like this:
#[derive(Queryable, Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = schema::posts)]
struct PostResponse {
    id: i32,
    user_id: i32,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    created_at: chrono::NaiveDateTime,
}

Then your function can look like this (ignoring actix-web parts):
async fn liked_posts(user_id: i32) -> Vec<PostResponse> {
    use schema::{likes, posts};

    let mut conn = establish_connection();
    let posts = likes::table
        .filter(likes::user_id.eq(user_id))
        .inner_join(posts::table)
        .select(PostResponse::as_select())
        .load::<PostResponse>(&mut conn)
        .expect("Error loading liked posts");

    posts
}

Full code on the playground (though it does not compile there since it doesn't have diesel).
Beyond that, there are some ORM functionalities documented in diesel::associations that allow you to quickly retrieve records by foreign key. However, it is fairly narrow and I don't think it would work for this particular use-case since you have an additional indirection (unless you want to do two queries: one to get the likes by user, another to get posts by likes, and even then the above is clearer to me and more performant).

Do you think the api benefits of rust compared to python Django are negligible. Since someone suggested an api’s performance is based on database speed and async. So even though rust is faster in raw speed it doesn't make it worth it? What do you think.

@Awm Without knowing your API does, its hard to say how much of a performance difference you're likely to see, but freakish is right that if you're mostly just shuffling bytes between client and database it may be negligible. I think Rust has a lot of benefits beyond just performance, but I don't want to get into a language spat. You really have to evaluate it for yourself which means actually measuring the performance difference if that is a deciding factor for you.

Let’s say a 100% instagram clone. With the goal of the lowest server cost, highest concurrency, more requests per second, shortest response time, latency, throughput. lowest instances needed. Rust has async diesel, sqlx. Django ORM isn't async by default but i’ve read you can get async engines for postgres.

@Awm If squeezing out the most performance is your only metric then obviously Rust will be better than Python. You already knew that. But please stop pressing me, comments are for clarifying answers, not for extended discussion. If my answer helped you with your Diesel problem, then consider upvoting or accepting it.
